# Empty for loop corrupts program while getting input from terminal with gets method in C

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am new to C and I was playing around with the program and wrote this program

```
int main(){
    char ** charList ;

    int listSize = 5;

    for(int a = 0; a < listSize; a++){
        char str [2];
        gets(str);
        charList[a] = str;
    }

    printf("program ended");

    return 0;
}
```

Which takes 5 inputs from terminal and prints **program ended**.

On the other hand, If I add simple empty for loop after `printf("program ended");` as the code below.

```
int main(){
    char ** charList ;

    int listSize = 5;

    for(int a = 0; a < listSize; a++){
        char str [2];
        gets(str);
        charList[a] = str;
    }

    printf("program ended");

    
    for(int b = 0; b < 0; b++){
       printf("loop");
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

I only added empty for loop and the program crashed. It only waits for one input and crashes. As much as I understood it might be a buffer error. But I could not understand how an empty loop crashes working program. Can someone explain what is wrong with the program.

Comment: But it was working before empty loop. I read that gets is very dangerous but it were working before empty loop.

Comment: Note that you can't usefully use those buffered `printf` statements for debugging without flushing the output, such as with a newline, or with `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: That's the nature of undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Comment: `gets()` is not just *deprecated*.  It has actually been *removed* from the language spec.  It is the only such function that I can name off the top of my head, and I'm not sure there are any others.

Comment: `char str [2];` would only succeed with a **single** character for each input. What are you entering with the "5 inputs"?

Comment: `char ** charList;` declares a pointer variable.  It does not cause that variable's value to *point to* any particular thing.  Attempting to use it as if it pointed to valid storage produces undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You do not allocate any memory to store the pointers.

```
char ** charList;
/*...*/ // 
charList[a] = str;  <-- access outside the bounds.
```

Solution:

```
    int listSize = 5;
    char *charList[listSize];
```

or

```
    char **charList = malloc(listSize * sizeof(*charList));
```

2. Do not use `gets`. use `fgets` instead (but your char array should be larger than two chars as you will read `\n` as well.
3. `charList[a] = str;` will assign the reference to the same memory so all elements of `charList` array will reference the same string. You need to allocate memory for the string and **copy** it.

```
    char charList[listSize][3];
    /* ... */
    strcpy(charList[a],str);
```

or

```
    charList[a] = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if(charList[a]) strcpy(charList[a],str);
```